# How to get the value of Dropdown on the specific field using ajax (mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

sorry for the bad title I cannot express the proper subject to my problem
since, I'm a newbie in MVC and ajax I have a problem

In view I prepared a dropdown where it list all the shoes name (Shoe Table), now the customer has to select it but the twist it must display the Shoesprice (Shoe Table) once it select a shoe name. the view code is given below

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.shoename, new SelectList(Model.ShoesModel,"shoename","shoename"), "Select Shoes Name", new {id="myDrop",@class="form-control" })
```

I have the script when you select it the item, this particular syntax is working
**Script:**

```
    $("#myDrop").change(function ()
        {
            var value = $(this).val();
            console.log(value);
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Customers/GetShoesPrice',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { shoesName: $(this).val() },
            success: function (data) {

             //how can I declare a value to get the and return the price
                }
                });
        }
```

But, i don't know how to create an ajax syntax (get the price according to shoe name), and set to a controller

thank you for help

Comment: as long as your MVC controller code in Customers/GetShoesPrice returns a value, then the value will ne returned in your data object defined against your success function. So if you are returning a double for instance it will just be data. If your controller returns and object then it will be data.xxxx

Comment: Can you show your `GetShoesPrice` Action

Comment: `
        public JsonResult GetShoesPrice(string shoesName)
        {
       
            var customerViewPrice = from c in _SBC.Shoeses
                           //Change the condition here
                           where c.shoename.ToString().Contains(shoesName)
                           select c.ShoesUnitPrice;
            return Json(customerViewPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`

Comment: In your success function the value will be available as: `data.customerViewPrice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to return single value only, just use `data` in AJAX `success` result to show returned price value:

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetShoesPrice(string shoesName) 
{ 
    var customerViewPrice = (from c in _SBC.Shoeses // Change the condition here 
    where c.shoename.Contains(shoesName) 
    select c.ShoesUnitPrice).FirstOrDefault(); // or SingleOrDefault() for one and only returned value

    return Json(customerViewPrice); 
}
```

**View (jQuery)**

```
$("#myDrop").change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/Customers/GetShoesPrice',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: { shoesName: value },
       success: function (data) {
           // set input element value which will be posted on form submit with DropDownListFor
           $('#price').val(data); 
       }
   });
}
```

Note that if you want to show list of `ShoesUnitPrice` from selected `shoesName`, you need to use `$.each()` loop to iterate returned array of price value.